# Crawling / Scraping sports website to collect players' stats, market value etc. with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I currently try to crawl a table on a website for a small "private project" (https://www.ligainsider.de/stats/kickbase/rangliste/feldspieler/gesamt/) containing stats regarding football players, their market value etc.

I basically would like to scrape the entire table that you can see on the website. However, I encounter some challenges, because some tag seem to be similar and I somehow can't manage to "access" them.

I successfully write "Spieler" (name), "Verein" (team) and "Punkte Spieltag" (points last matchday) into a list in Python. Can you help me to get the information for "Position", "Marktwert", "Einsätze" etc.?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Define configuration variables
URL = "https://www.ligainsider.de/stats/kickbase/rangliste/feldspieler/gesamt/"
output_path = "C:[...].xlsx"

# Make request to the website
page = requests.get(URL)

# Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

# Find all rows with information
table_rows = soup.find_all("tr")

# Create empty lists to hold the data
player_names = []
team_names = []
points_matchday = []

# Loop through each row and extract the data
for row in table_rows:
    # Extract player name
    player_name = row.find("a")
    if player_name is not None:
        player_name_text = player_name.text.strip()
        player_names.append(player_name_text)

    # Extract team name
    team_name = row.find("a", {"class", "text-thin"})
    if team_name is not None:
        team_name_text = team_name.text.strip()
        team_names.append(team_name_text)

    # Extract last matchday points
    points_matchday_name = row.find("td", {"class", "text-right"})
    if points_matchday_name is not None:
        points_matchday_name_text = points_matchday_name.text.strip()
        points_matchday.append(points_matchday_name_text)

print(player_names)
print(team_names)
print(points_matchday)
```

This is a exemplary HTML code block from one row (= player) I want to crawl. Player in this case is "Kimmich":

```
<tr data-anchor-rowfilter="filter1" role="row" class="odd">

    <td data-criteria-rowfilter="" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
            <li>joshuakimmich</li>
            <li>joshuakimmich</li>
            <li>fcbayernmunchen</li>
            <li>fcbayernmünchen</li>
            <li>mittelfeldspieler</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td class="sorting_1">1</td>
    <td class="text-left">
        <strong><a href="/joshua-kimmich_5768/">Joshua Kimmich</a></strong>
    </td>
    <td class="text-left"><a class="text-thin" href="/fc-bayern-muenchen/1/">FC Bayern München</a></td>
    <td class="text-left">Mittelfeldspieler</td>
        <td class="text-right">164</td>
    <td class="text-right">50.432.349€</td>
    <td class="text-right">21</td>
    <td class="text-right">162,10</td>
    <td class="text-right"><strong>3.404</strong></td>
    
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can crawl all table like that and then just use [re](/questions/tagged/re) to organize it. There are some errors which club names also crawling in lists but you can delete them easily. Don't forget to importing re.

```
import re
r =requests.get('https://www.ligainsider.de/stats/kickbase/rangliste/feldspieler/gesamt/')
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.select('#DataTable > tbody > tr')
for x in table:
    text = (x.text)
    name_regex = re.compile(r'([A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+)(?!\s\w+)')
    names = re.findall(name_regex, text)
    print(names)
```

Comment: Very cool. Thank you very much. I didn't know that this possibility exists (... not surprising as I'm very new to Python). I will definitely try this today.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to scrape table data is to use [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html('https://www.ligainsider.de/stats/kickbase/rangliste/feldspieler/gesamt/')[0].iloc[:,1:]
```

However you also could get your goal iterating all the rows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.ligainsider.de/stats/kickbase/rangliste/feldspieler/gesamt/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
data = []
for row in soup.select('#DataTable tbody tr'):
    data.append({
            'player':row.a.text,
            'link':row.a.get('href'),
            'team':row.select_one('td>a').text
        }
    )
data
```

Answer (score 0):

@elkhan:
Thank you very much! It works now :)

If anyone is interested, this is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html("https://www.ligainsider.de/stats/kickbase/rangliste/feldspieler/gesamt/")[0].iloc[:,1:]

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.ligainsider.de/stats/kickbase/rangliste/feldspieler/gesamt/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = []
for row in soup.select("#DataTable tbody tr"):
    data.append({
            "Player": row.a.text,
            "Team": row.select_one("td>a").text,
            "Position": row.select("td.text-left")[2].text.strip(),
            "Points Matchday": row.select("td.text-right")[0].text.strip(),
            "Market value": row.select("td.text-right")[1].text.strip(),
            "Appearances": row.select("td.text-right")[2].text.strip(),
            "Avrg. points": row.select("td.text-right")[3].text.strip(),
            "Total points": row.select("td.text-right")[4].text.strip()
        }
    )
data
print(data)
```